# Why is the CSS not being applied in my Angular project that uses the Angular Materials Side Nav Bar?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have just started learning Angular and came across [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6qhzG7mObU) on how to use Angular materials side nav bar. However, when I followed the steps in the tutorial, the website displayed did not use CSS.

These were the steps I followed:

1. Create my Angular application.
2. Execute ng generate @angular/material:navigation
3. Import necessary modules in the modules.ts file.
4. Put `<app-nav></app-nav>` into the app.component.html file.

And this was the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO9lS.png).

Edit- I even tried copying the contents of main-nav.component.css to the global styles.css as suggested in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228279/angular-material-sidenav-css-not-applied), but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the angular material's prebuilt theme in global style.scss file.

Without this, none of the styles of angular material component would be applied.

Add following line in style.scss file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. However, the menu icon (three horizontal lines) is still not being shown, it appears as the text "menu". My code is exactly the same as the tutorial. Is there any other css to be imported? By the way, I am not using scss in my project, only CSS.

Comment: Did you add MatIconModule in app.module file?

Comment: If yes, then the icon's visibility might be hidden or the color might be same as that of the background color. You will have to inspect the element and check it out.

Comment: Ok, got it. I had to import a CSS file for the icons as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796212/angular-material-icons-not-working. Apparently there were quite a few things the tutorial didn't cover. Thanks for the answer.